# Show a limited function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Not sure about the translated term *limited* (from German); perhaps *cut-off* function?

**Problem statement**

Let $f$ be a measurable function in a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $C>0$. Show that the following function is measurable:

$$f_C(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f(x)  & \mbox{if } |f(x)| \leq C \\
  C & \mbox{if } f(x) > C \\
                -C & \mbox{if } f(x) < -C
 \end{array}
\right.$$

**Clarification**

By measure space it is meant: An ordered tuple $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, where $\Omega$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets in $\Omega$, is called a *measurable space*.

**My attempt**

Since $f$ is measurable, then $f_C$ is measurable when $|f(x)| < C$.

It should be trivial to prove that a constant function is measurable.

I'm not sure how to approach $f_C$ at $C$. Perhaps: We have shown that $f_C$ is measurable at all points except $f(x)=C$, but a single point has measure $0$. However this seems very hand-wavy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you have a theorem that say that a product and a sum of meaurable function is measurable. Remark that

$$f_C(x)=C\boldsymbol 1_{f(x)>C}(x)-C\boldsymbol 1_{f(x)<-C}(x)+f(x)\boldsymbol 1_{f(x)\in [-C,C]}(x),$$
allow you to conclude very easily.